# Running an object with a synchronized method and normal method, concurrently?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

Is it just that two synchronised methods that can't run concurrently?

For example, someone codes 2 Java classes.

```
public class A {
    public synchronized void a1(){   
    //do something   }
    public void a2(){
    //do something   }
    public synchronized int a3(){
    int var = 0;
    //do something changing var
    return var;   } }


public class B {

  public void b1(){
    //do something
  }


  public synchronized int b2(){   
    int var = 0;
    //do something changing var
    return var;
  }

  public void b3(){
    //do something
  }
}
```

With a main method,

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  A firstA = new A();
  A secondA = new A();
  B firstB = newB();

  //create some threads that perform operations on firstA, secondA and first B and start them
}
```

Assuming they run in parallel and call methods on the created objects and also assuming that none of these methods are prevented by other mechanisms from running currently.

Out of the methods in the example I gave, are there any that **cannot** be run **concurrently** if called at the same time by 2 different threads?

By running **concurrently** I mean, they will be sequenced so that one will finish before the other starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is no other synchronization involved, the only calls that will be mutually excluded are:

1. `firstA.a1()` vs `firstA.a1()`
2. `firstA.a1()` vs `firstA.a3()`
3. `secondA.a1()` vs `secondA.a1()`
4. `secondA.a1()` vs `secondA.a3()`
5. `firstB.b2()` vs `firstB.b2()`

This is because synchronized blocks have to use **the same lock** for them to have an effect on each other. When you mark a whole method as `synchronized`, the lock object will be the value of `this`. So methods in `firstA` will be completely independent of methods of `secondA` or `firstB`, because **they use different locks**.

The methods in your code that aren't marked `synchronized` won't even attempt to acquire any lock at all, they can run whenever they want.

*Please note that mutual exclusion is just one aspect of multithreading. For your programme to work correctly, you also have to consider things like visibility and safe publication.*

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the answer depends on what "something" you "do" when you "do something", and since you don't show that, no one can answer. That's what happens when you omit the significant information. Don't omit the significant information.

What we can say is that the synchronized methods in `A` do not use the same lock as the synchronized methods in `B`.

If multiple threads access the same data, then they must synchronize with each other. The only way for threads to synchronize with each other is to use the same means of synchronization. If that's the use of `synchronized`, then they must synchronize on the same monitor (lock). So if the `A` methods and `B` methods access the same data from different threads, and who can tell if they do from what you show? then they won't work as shown.

If any of the unsynchronized methods access the same data from different threads, and the part you didn't show does not have other effective synchronization means, then they won't work.

All this depends on what you decided not to show us.

Comment: To be fair, you can answer the mutual exclusion question without knowing what they do (assuming the methods themselves don't do any extra locking). But as you say that still falls short of answering the question of correctness.

Comment: "assuming the methods themselves don't do any extra locking"? But you can't assume that, and I called that out. Your comment amounts to "you can answer the mutual exclusion question without knowing what they do except if they do certain things we don't know".

Comment: Come on, that isn't that big an assumption. Obviously if I copy in the code that does synchronization, and I ask about synchronization, the bit that I omitted will contain no synchronization.

Comment: Assumptions don't have sizes. It is an assumption. You don't have the information that your assumption is correct nor not correct. Even if the assumption "isn't that big", it's big enough to turn a correct approach into an incorrect approach.

Comment: Of course they do, it's why we have Occam's razor. But never mind, I've answered the question already.

Answer (score 0):

All of them can run at the same time without inturrupting each other.
because each thread handles different instance, there's no need for them to wait to what so ever synconized method.